# Multiple step-down of DC voltage in one circuit

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi

I need to read some signals from a machine which outputs the bits in form of 0 and 24 VDC.

I will be using Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB) or an Arduino Mega to read the same, however since Raspberry Pi/Mega accepts only 5.0 VDC, I will have to decrease the voltage from 24V to 5V.

I understand that this can easily be done using a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) (or a combination of a resistance and a 5V zener), but the real issue is that there are about 30 different outputs that I can get from the host machine.

Is there a way I can step-down the voltage on 30 different pins *with common ground* ? I am not sure if any similar device is already available, but if it is there would be great.

Comment: 30x voltage dividers seems the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Although Andy Aka's solution is probably cheaper, four SN65HVS880 may also do the job.

> The SN65HVS880 is a 24-V, eight-channel, digital-input serializer for high-channel density digital input modules of PC and PLC based systems in industrial automation. In combination with galvanic isolators the device completes the interface between the 24-V sensor outputs of the field-side and the low-voltage controller inputs at the control-side.

Comment: Interesting chip +1

Comment: Prefer Andy's solution.  Adding this chip adds semis that increase the FITs, reduces reliability, adds complexity that is not needed – because the resistor divider solution works, is robust, and reliable.